# script to look up and compare definitions of words in 2 online dictionaries

Tags: scripting

I'd like to look up different definitions of a given word, e.g. "obey", in two or three online dictionaries of my choice, e.g. Longman, Cambridge, Oxford. Then have them listed one by one in Terminal. Can this be turned into a script? Where do I start?

Comment: Do these dictionaries provide a REST-like web interface that is free to use?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be piggybacking on an existing dictionary aggregator such as [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/) or [One Look](https://www.onelook.com/) and simply converting their output into text form.

For instance, for The Free Dictionary you can define the following function:

```
$ tfd() {
  if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]; then echo "Syntax: webdict <word>"; return; fi
  python3 -c "
import bs4,requests
sel = '[data-src=hm], [data-src=hc_dict], [data-src=rHouse]'
page = requests.get('https://www.thefreedictionary.com/$1').text
for d in bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser').select(sel): print(d, end='<hr>')" |
  w3m -dump -T text/html;
}
```

which you could then use to look up words:

```
$ tfd fain
```

(Note that the python3, python3-requests, python3-bs4 and w3m packages are needed for this to work.)

An obvious downside is that you will be limited to the selection of dictionaries and their formatting provided by the aggregator.

Another option is to use a console dictionary proper such as [sdcv](https://dushistov.github.io/sdcv/). However, not all online dictionaries provide APIs for automated access which will limit the number of dictionaries you can use legally with this approach.